# Include tags in the body of a post

Tags: shortcode, tags

it feel like this should be easy. I want to add the post tags inside the body of some posts. I was thinking that creating a shortcode may be the answer. I came across these 2 pieces of code:

To display the tags...

```
<p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
```

To create a shortcode...

```
function show_current_year(){
    return date('Y');
}
add_shortcode('show_current_year', 'show_current_year');
```

I can't combine the 2! Can anyone help? The only other solution would be to insert the php directly in the post but I think I'd need a plug-in to do that and I'm a bit wary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `the_tags()` to the shortcode:

```
function wpse_82190_tags(){

    return the_tags();
}
add_shortcode('tags', 'wpse_82190_tags');
```

Comment: Thank you that works a treat - I expected it to position the tags where the shortcode is placed rather than at the top of the post but I'll have a play and see what's going on.

Comment: `get_the_tag_list()` will return the result where the shortcode is; http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tag_list

Comment: Hi Michael thank you - I'll have a look at that. Sounds like it could result in precisely what I'm after. As it is the existing code is implemented and is fine but being a perfectionist control of positioning would be a dream!